# How can I use itertools to simplify this nested for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops, python-itertools

How can I use itertools to simplify this nested for loop?

```py
# pytest file:

def get_test_cases():

    with open("file_path.yml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as index_file:
        data = yaml.safe_load(index_file)

    for vendor_dict in data:
        for vendor_name, class_list in vendor_dict.items():
            for class_dict in class_list:
                for class_name, method_list in class_dict.items():
                    for method_dict in method_list:
                        for function, test_list in method_dict.items():
                            for test_case in test_list:
                                yield vendor_name, class_name, function, test_case

@pytest.mark.parametrize("iteration", get_test_cases())
def test_network(iteration, monkeypatch):
    """Performs pytest using info provided from test case"""

    (vendor_name, class_name, function, test_case) = iteration

    # Use data above to perform pytest
    # Code omitted
```

Sample Data is in YAML:

```yaml
# YAML file:

- cisco:
    - CiscoClass:
        - get_interface_stats:
            - test_description: "test interface stats"
              function_input: "Gig1/1/1"
              expected_output: "show interfaces Gig1/1/1"

- juniper:
    - JuniperClass:
        - get_vlan_info: 
            - test_description: "test get_vlan_info"
              function_input: "10"
              expected_output: "show vlan 10"
```

**Explanation**

The YAML file contains parameters uses for building test cases. We have a block of test cases for Cisco, and other test cases for Juniper.
So the structure is this vendor --> name of class --> function --> test case data

Function get_test_cases in my pytest file will load the YAML file contents, and then iterates through the contents, and yield data for each test case.
Function test_network consumes this data, and performs the actual testing.

I am trying to find an alternative to the nested for loops so that I can raise my pylint rating... if this is even possible.

Comment: Can you add sample data and corresponding output?

Comment: I don't think there's anything in itertools that helps you deal with such a deeply nested data structure. You might be able to write your own recursive function that iterates through arbitrarily nested lists and dicts, but if this is the only situation you need to do this in, it wouldn't necessarily be clearer than what you already have. If the data file is under your control, you might want to redesign it with a less nested format.

Comment: You should provide a sample of data as user @trincot suggests and explain what you're trying to do here - if you're selecting this data from a data structure that contains a lot of other data, there may be no straightforward way to do this, but if you share a sample, people may have some useful suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @cards Please show how to do that with such dependent loops, I'd very much like to see that.

Comment: @cards I really don't think so. `product` repeats the same values at each position. This code doesn't (unless the data happens to have that property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following to make it a bit compacter:

```
def testcases(data, level=0):
    if level == 3:
        for case in data:
            yield (case,)
    else:
        for record in data:
            for name in record:
                for case in testcases(record[name], level + 1):
                    yield (name,) + case
```

or

```
def testcases(data, level=0):
    if level == 6:
        for case in data:
            yield (case,)
    elif level % 2 == 0:
        for record in data:
            yield from testcases(record, level + 1)
    else:
        for name, records in data.items():
            for case in testcases(records, level + 1):
                yield (name,) + case
```

and then

```
def get_test_cases():
    with open("file_path.yml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as index_file:
        data = yaml.safe_load(index_file)
    yield from testcases(data)
```

With your sample file this

```
for case in get_test_cases():
    print(case)
```

does produce

```
('cisco', 'CiscoClass', 'get_interface_stats', {'test_description': 'test interface stats', 'function_input': 'Gig1/1/1', 'expected_output': 'show interfaces Gig1/1/1'})
('juniper', 'JuniperClass', 'get_vlan_info', {'test_description': 'test get_vlan_info', 'function_input': '10', 'expected_output': 'show vlan 10'})
```